# PHP include() through HTTP makes Apache time out

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, centos6

I have a problem with ExpressionEngine2 after moving from an old server to WHM/cPanel running on CentOS6.4. Simple test code to reproduce that issue:

```
<?php 
        $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        include($protocol . '://' . $host . '/header.html'); 
?>
    <p> Main text...</p>
<?php
        include($protocol . '://' . $host . '/footer.html'); 
?>
```

Where header.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

and footer.html looks like:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Creates Apache time out:

```
Warning: include(http://www.domain.com/header.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/domain/public_html/test/index.php on line 5

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://www.domain.com/header.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/test/index.php on line 5

Main text...

Warning: include(http://www.domain.com/footer.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/domain/public_html/test/index.php on line 12

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'http://www.domain.com/footer.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/domain/public_html/test/index.php on line 12
```

Any clue what can be wrong with Apache or PHP configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Likely nothing.  The error message says it all:

```
Warning: include(http://www.domain.com/footer.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/domain/public_html/test/index.php on line 12
```

The connection to the site for the remote include timed out.  This is some kind of connectivity issue; perhaps there is a firewall or a routing issue in the way (it's impossible to say without information about your environment, and in particular where the two servers are in relation to each other).

If for some reason you are using remote includes to access files on the same server (why would you do that), try using a browser on that server to query itself.  If you can't, chances are apache isn't listening on the loopback interface, but your new `hosts` file is causing the domain name to resolve to `127.0.0.1`.